# Splitting a vector into vectors of different length

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to split a vector with 90 arrays to 5 vectors with different lengths. The length of each vector is determined according to a normalized length like this:

```
nl=[0.1642 .1516 .1259 .5583]
```

Therefore the length of each vector is

```
length=90*[0.1642 .1516 .1259 .5583]
```

But these lengths are not integer, and if i try to round this the length of will not equal to 90, it might be 89, 90, 91 or even 92 due to round of error.
I would appreciate if anyone could assist me to write a code for this.

Comment: you could round the lengths as you said (preferably with `fix`/`floor`), and in the end if they don't sum to 90, just add the remaining elements to the last bin.. I think `histc` can also help here.

Comment: You say that you want 5 vectors, but your lengths vector has only 4 members.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known problem only with a different terminology. Think of an election where `nl` are the votes and you have 90 seats to distribute.

You will find dozens of algorithms, I would use the D'Hondt method.

Implementation in Matlab is available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30245-political-apportionment), for some theoretical background check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Party-list_PR)

Answer (score 0):

My naive implementation:

```
% some normalized lengths
len = rand(1,4);
len = len ./ sum(len);

% convert to integers (round towards zeros)
d = fix(len.*90);

% fix the count by adding remaning elements to the last bin
d(end) = d(end) + (90-sum(d));

% sanity check
assert(sum(d)==90)
```

---

### EDIT:

Here is a better solution using `HISTC`:

```
edges = cumsum(len.*90);
[counts,idx] = histc(1:90, [0 edges(1:end-1) Inf]);
counts(end) = [];
```

Now `counts` contain number of elements in each bin, and `idx` contains the bin index for each of the 90 elements.

---

**WARNING:** The two methods above might give less than ideal splits in corner cases. See @Daniel's comments for examples..

Comment: Be aware, that this may be far of an expected "fair" distribution. example: `len=[2;ones(88,1);.1];`

Comment: well done, that's a good counter-example :) It assigned `[1,0,...,0,89]`, which is totally wrong! How about my second method using HISTC? I get `[1,1,...,1,1]` with that example..

Comment: Obviously for such corner cases, I recommend using the proportional "vote distribution" schemes you mentioned!

Comment: `len=[1.005,repmat([.99,1.01],[1,44]),0.995]./90;` I would expect `counts=ones(1,90)` but a optimal solution is not defined in the question.

Comment: @Daniel: yet again you beat my code :) HISTC method gave me `[1,0,2,0,2,...,0,2,1]` which is not ideal. Hmm now I'm thinking I should delete my answer, since it doesn't handle these corner cases well...